# using rich-markdown-editor react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use [rich-markdown-editor](https://github.com/outline/rich-markdown-editor) to get values but the method am using is not modular. Can someone suggest a better way. I have tried both `onChange` and `onSave` but cannot seem to get them to work.According to their documentation

> onSave({ done: boolean }): void
> This callback is triggered when the user explicitly requests to save using a keyboard shortcut, Cmd+S or Cmd+Enter. You can use this as a signal to save the document to a remote server.

> onChange(() => value): void
> This callback is triggered when the contents of the editor changes, usually due to user input such as a keystroke or using formatting options. You may use this to locally persist the editors state.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Editor from "rich-markdown-editor";

const Whiteboard = () => {
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Your Content</h1>
        <Editor id="123" value={content} onChange={setContent} />
      </div>
      {content}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Whiteboard;
```

Comment: It's unclear from your question what the problem is. Is the content in the editor not being persisted?

Comment: Yes...I want to store the content in the state in markdown format the persist it to the database but I can not figure how to do that

Comment: `useState` is for preserving data within your application, i.e. so that you can reference it from different functions (using the `content` variable). Saving that variable to a database like SQL would be a different task; there are lots of great answers here already about how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<Editor id="123" value={content} onChange={(value) => setContent(value()} />
```